# How do I stop Word from selecting each FormField as I read their values in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a template document in Word 2013 that has the user fill in a large number of Legacy Text FormFields.  At the end of the document, I've included a button which compiles the answers into a string devoid of formatting, then copies it to the clipboard.

It *works*, but as each FormField is read, the Word document skips back and forth between each text field and the end of the document.  It's visually alarming.  Is there a way to gather the values of each FormField without Word moving the cursor/focus to each field as it is read?

Here's a sample of the code:

```
Private Sub cmdCreateNote_Click()

    Call cmdClearNote_Click

    Dim ff As FormFields
    Set ff = ActiveDocument.FormFields

    Dim Output As String
    Output = ff("ddReviewType").Result & vbCrLf

    If ff("chFacInfo").Result Then
        Dim FacInfo
        FacInfo = Array("Field1: ", _
            "Field2: ", _
            "Field3: ", _
            "Field4: ", _
            "Field5: ")

        Output = Output & "FIRST SECTION" & vbCrLf

        For Index = 1 To 5
            If ff("chFacInfo" & Index).Result Then
                Output = Output & FacInfo(Index - 1) & ff("txFacInfo" & Index).Result & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next

        Output = Output & vbCrLf
    End If

    Dim FORange As Range
    Set FORange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("FinalOutput").Range
    FORange.Text = Output
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "FinalOutput", FORange

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="FinalOutput"
    Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

It appears that every time I access ActiveDocument.FormFields( x ).Result, the document focus goes to that element, then drops back to the end of the document again.

Any pointers?

Comment: Try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before going through the FormFields and then setting it to `True` after, in order to minimize screen updating.

Comment: @OlleSjögren suggestion will work for the visual aspect. Have you tried a `For Each` loop over the `ff` object e.g. `Dim field As FormField For Each field in ff ....`

Comment: +1 for a well-asked question AND "Aloha" :D

Comment: @OlleSjögren, your comment was the solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Posting comment as answer, since it worked!

Try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before going through the FormFields and then setting it to `True` after, in order to minimize screen updating.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Bookmark` object instead of the `FormField`. This will allow you to access the properties without changing the screen focus. See answer on [Suppress unwanted jumping/scrolling on Word 2013 VBA Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889709/suppress-unwanted-jumping-scrolling-on-word-2013-vba-macro/26891768#26891768) for specifics on how to do this.

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("myFieldName").Range.Fields(1).Result
```